FastAPI Stops working afterawhile and then reboots after multiple failed requests
I have deployed my FastAPI onto azure in a container, problem is after awhile I'm getting this error
2024-04-18T09:48:52.022078363Z: [INFO]  fail: Middleware[0]
2024-04-18T09:48:52.022122364Z: [INFO]        Failed to forward request to http://(eg an ip address) Encountered a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception after 300002.524ms with message: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 300 seconds elapsing.. Check application logs to verify the application is properly handling HTTP traffic.Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---Starting Live Log Stream ---

Initially, I thought the issue might be due to using Uvicorn to run the API. I switched to Gunicorn and installed all the necessary packages, but the problem persists. The API functions correctly for a while, but if left unattended for some time, I return to find the same error occurring.
Here is my docker file
FROM python:3.12.0

WORKDIR /testapi

COPY ./requirements.txt /testapi/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  --upgrade -r /testapi/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade uvloop

COPY ./ /testapi

CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "--workers", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80"]


I tried switching from uvicorn to gunicorn

Share your code or repository.

Are you deploying to Azure Container Instance or Azure container Web app?

i'll work on providing a repository for viewing, i'm using ACA.

i am using Azure web app

For some strange reason it worked after switching form Azure App service to Azure container apps
